# How generate a report of diff between two baselines in Clearcase UCM?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to generate a report of what changed (files and lines of code) between two baselines.  I was able to see the activities and versions but is there a way to print out, say each file name and the diff of the versions between the two baselines?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get back all the versions of `B1` and `B2`, and for each version, to::

- get the name of the element (See [`fmt_ccase`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm): `cleartool descr -fmt "%En"`)
- get the most recent version `V1` of the baseline 1 (`B1` being the most recent baseline)
- get the oldest version `V2` of the baseline 2 (`B2` being the oldest baseline)
- `cleartool diff V1 V2`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527550/how-to-retrieve-the-list-of-files-modified-across-base-lines-in-clear-case