# How to retrieve the list of files modified across base lines in clear case

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I need to retrieve a list of all the files that have been checked-in across baselines along with the owner name. I tried using the cleartool lsact command :

However, this command fetches just for one task and is a bit cumbersome to use. Is there a command which will retrieve all the tasks if I specify two baselines?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A  command like:

```
 cleartool diffbl -act bl1@\apvob bl2@\apvob
```

will give you the list of activities which have new versions between baselines bl1 and bl2.

However, to get the list of *files* (ie elements, as in files or directories, and not *versions* as in all the updated versions even for a same file), the best way is to:

- ensure those baselines are "full" baseline: promote them to full if needed:

```
    cleartool chbl -full bl1@\apvob
    cleartool chbl -full bl2@\apvob
```

(if they were already full, this command won't do anything)

- list all elements which have the `bl1` and  `bl2` labels on different versions:

```
cleartool find -all -element '{lbtype_sub(REL1) && lbtype_sub(REL2)}' ^ 
  -version '{(lbtype(REL1) && ! lbtype(REL2)) || ^
  (lbtype(REL2) && !lbtype(REL1))}' -print
```

See "[Find changes between labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462407/find-changes-between-labels/2464604#2464604)".
Note that this last question also mentions the "**report builder** packaged with ClearCase, which is interesting if you are after a solution involving a GUI and not a CLI (command line):

[image: report builder]

Again, if those baselines are full, you can use it to list (under `Elements/Labels`) either "`Elements Changed Between Two Labels`" or "`Versions Changed Between Two Labels`" depending on which you need.

Comment: Hi .. I tried this command but it is giving me a list of activities. What I am looking for is a list of all the files that have been modified for each activitiy across all activities.

Comment: @Sai I was editing my answer: see the edited answer, or as another alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256649/how-to-get-the-list-of-the-checkin-files-between-two-clearcase-ucm-lables-in-uni

Comment: @Sai just added the "report builder" option as well

Comment: Hi... thanks a lot for your help. Actually, I am very new to using clear case commands and I am running on Windows platform. I went through the links that you have mentioned, but all of them seem to throw some errors!!

Comment: @Sai: don't hesitate to add in those comments the commands you are typing and the error message you get: I will fix those commands

Comment: Hi.. tried using this command cleartool diffbl -activities -elements baseline:[first_Baseline]@\VOB baseline:[second_Baseline]@\VOB. This command fetches a list of activities and files, however it contains some deliver baseline info as well. I am not sure it correctly fetches the required details. Also, it does not give me the owner name. Can you please help?

Comment: @Sai: the diffbl -act if for listing activities, which isn't what you want. For the proper syntax, see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm

Comment: @Sai: I would advise the `chbl` and `find` approach.