# cleartool mkbl comamnd hangs and never returns?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

when i execute cleartool mkbl  it hangs and never returns. The window has to be killed and restart.
what might be the possible reasons behind it and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Since UCM [`cleartool mkbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm) put a baseline on all modified components, that means that, behind the scene, it will call [mklabel](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm).
And that can takes time, if there are *a lot of* new or modified files to labelled, one by one.

If this isn't the issue, then you need to check the logs (both of the client and the server), in order to see if all the necessary services are in place (like the albd server, the lock manager, ...).
You can use [`cleartool getlog`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm) for that.

Comment: It hangs at this point:cleartool: Warning: Searching PVOBs for baselines that depend upon
baseline "T_LTZEBRA_COMP_WELLS_00_TL15_131005.0.2078".
This may take a few minutes...Do you think the promotional level has to be in certain state?

Comment: @I would recommend making sure that baseline is a full one (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10527967/6309). But I have seen that warning before, and depending on the size of the history, that check can takes hours. So try to give it a bit of time before cancelling that command.

Comment: The replica of the above baseline is in different site that might be the reason taking it so long i.e around 3 hrs.

Comment: Before it used to take only few mins, now it is taking too long. what other aspects might be the possible reason behind it beside multi-site?

Comment: @user2370590 mainly the size of the component being labelled. If they are too many files, that also can take a while.