# I can't see the added value of using lbtype_sub versus lbtype?

Tags: clearcase

I have just finish to read this IBM technote but I didn't understand:
[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [`cleartool find` man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) and the [query language](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm)

> `lbtype (label-type-name)`
>
> In all cases, **TRUE if the object itself is labeled label-type-name**. (Because elements and branches cannot have labels, this primitive can be true only for versions.)
>
> `lbtype_sub (label-type-name)`:
>
> - With elements:
>     TRUE if the element has a version that is labeled label-type-name.
> - With branches:
>     TRUE if the branch has a version that is labeled label-type-name.
> - With versions:
>     TRUE if the version itself is labeled label-type-name.

So a `cleartool find . -version` would use `lbtype()`, whereas a search on elements (`cleartool find -all -element`) will have to use `lbtype_sub()`.

Comment: Note: I have been using both in the same `find` query before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10527967/6309